# quotient group G/N order and isomorphic group

Tags: group-theory

Consider group

$$G= \left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
0 & a^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \colon a,b\in \mathbb{R}, a> 0\right \}$$
with usual matrix multiplication.

Let

$$N= \left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b\\ 
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \colon b\in \mathbb{R}\right \}.$$

Question is to verify following two statements

1. $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$ and quotient group $G/N$ is of finite order
2. $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$ and quotient group $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$

My attempt:

I have checked that $N$ is a subgroup and it is also a normal subgroup.
My doubt:
 I need suggestions to 
1. find  $G/N$.
2. Then how to see if it has finite order or not and also how to see if it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statement (1) is wrong; $G/N$ is actually of infinite order (which is in Statement (2))

Consider the group

$$D=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & a^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \colon a\in\mathbb{R}^+\right\}.$$

Show that $D\cong  \mathbb{R}^+$.

Consider the natural map from $G$ to $D$

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a^{-1}\end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & a^{-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Check that this is a **surjective homomorphism** with kernel $N$, which will answer your question.

Comment: I want to know how did find that there is such natural map from G to D. how do I think about these things?

Comment: Take product of two elements $A,B$ in $G$; the non-diagonal entry in the product $AB$ will be quite complicated, but the diagonal entries in $AB$ are the products of diagonal entries in $A$ and $B$. Thus, sending any element of $G$ to a diagonal matrix will define a homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense atleast in this question

Answer (score 2):

There is a shortcut way of doing this, and it's an important idea to remember.

> A subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is normal if and only if it is the kernel of some homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$.

You already know this in the form of the first isomorphism theorem, with $H=G/N$ and $\varphi$ surjective, but sometimes there can be other, more obvious choices for $H$ if you take a step back and allow $\varphi$ to not be surjective. (Then, to use the isomorphism theorem, you instead consider $\varphi(G)$, which will be proper in $H$.)

But let's get down to brass tacks: in this case, you want to figure out a good choice for $H$ and $\varphi$ so that $N$ ends up being the kernel of $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$. What do you have to do to $\left(\begin{array}{ll}a&b\\0&a^{-1}\end{array}\right)$ so that it is sent to the identity if and only if $a=1$? What kind of map can you make to accomplish that?

After you figure the previous part out, my second hint is that you can find another homomoprhism (an isomorphism) from $G/H$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  I think this part will be obvious once you get the previous part.

Comment: I see its not easy to guess what choice of $\phi$to make. There has to some system to find that right choice. In a exam u can't wait enough. Plz help little more

Comment: @singularity The other answerer gave you the answer, so, look at that answer and then look at my hint again.  The system is exactly to *construct the map that sends the normal subgroup to the identity*.  If you review this case until you understand how this is done, then compare to another example, you will understand how to find other answers of this kind on a test. You don't have to *guess* the map at all: it is as simple as it can possibly be. You just change what needs to be changed to get what you want. Consider this deeply and you will understand.